# Multiply a value in coffee script

Tags: coffeescript

```
 element.textContent = value + "%"
```

I'm new to coffee script and I'm trying to multiply a value.  I've tried the following and none of them work.  Not sure what I'm doing wrong here?

```
 element.textContent = {value*100} + "%"
 element.textContent = (value*100) + "%"
 element.textContent = value*100 + "%"
```

Comment: What do you get? `value*100 + "%"` and `(value*100) + "%"` should both work.

Comment: I'm just getting the original value.

Comment: [Works fine](http://coffeescript.org/#try:value%20%3D%206%0Aconsole.log%20value%20*%20100%20%2B%20'%25'), what are you doing that's different than the linked example? Can you provide a functional demo of your problem?

Comment: Ahh, odd.  I'm trying to change this dashing widget to provide the value as response times (in miliseconds) as opposed to a percentage.  I figured if I multiplied it I would get the decimal point moved.  I removed the Math.Floor the dashing widget has in the coffeescript.   Here is the link to the dashing widget code.               https://gist.github.com/mdirienzo/6716905

Answer (score 1):

Simple. Just change your code to this:

```
element.textContent = String(value * 100) + "%"
```

Hope this helped!

Comment: `"#{value * 100}%"` would be more idiomatic CoffeeScript.